# Rails 3 activerecord query where clause with timezone

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

I have a problem with my rails application (rails 3.2.x, MySQL 5.x). Sample case to produce:

1. set `time_zone='Hanoi'` in `application.rb`
2. model `Post`
3. new post created at `2013-06-28 01:00:00` (date of server: `Fri Jun 28 01:00:00 ICT 2013`)

MySQL is config with timezone `SYSTEM`. `created_at` of new post will be store with value `2013-06-27 18:00:00`

How can i find all posts in `2013-06-28` in rails app?

```
Post.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today)
```

Is this timezone configuration correct or not?

Comment: Solve this problem with command: `Post.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.beginning_of_day + 1.day)`

Comment: You can answer your own questions and even accept those answers.